# PHP error. “ Undefined index” the data from the form won't insert into the mysql database

Tags: php, sql, insert, indexing

it is a error in the VALUES in the php. It says it is a undefined index in every single value. I have tried for a long time now, but i can't figure out what the problem is. is it in my database or inside the code? Please help me :)

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>A small example page to insert some data in to the MySQL database using PHP</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="navn" /><br><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="adresse" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("forum", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO bruker (navn, adresse)
VALUES
('$_POST[navn]',
'$_POST[adresse]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Stop using the deprecated `mysql_` functions and switch to MySQLi or PDO instead 2) Don't blindly insert values into your MySQL query. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection 3) You can use `isset()` to check if the value is actually defined in your `$_POST` array. `print_r($_POST);` will list the entire contents.

Comment: You should not use MySql as it is deprecated. use PDO or MySqli instead!

Comment: You're tying to get the index of an array in the wrong way. `$_POST[navn]` it's in fact `$_POST['navn']` and `$_POST['adresse']`. But you've got bigger issues than that: you're blindly inserting values in the database. That's a big no-no. You should look into prepared statements and use `mysqli` instead.

Comment: are you writing html and php in a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your post value will work once submit button is clicked

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="submit" />

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("forum", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO bruker (navn, adresse)
VALUES
('$_POST[navn]',
'$_POST[adresse]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
}
?>
```

you can also hide your warning by using

error_reporting(0);

Comment: -1 for "your post value will work once submit button is clicked".the OP is already using method =post so whn you will click on submit the data will transferred to php file.giving name to submit is a good practice but it doesnot effect anything when there is only one submit button.

Comment: The error is gone, but the data don not insert into my database

Comment: @Rishabh Raj !!!Its working for him now ,what you have written it will work but it will show warning.And yes thanks for -1

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use old mysql functions. Switch to mysqli or PDO instead. I've updated the code for BASIC security, but prepared statements give much more security.

Try this:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pw","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$navn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['navn']);
$adresse = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['adresse']);

$sql="INSERT INTO bruker (navn, adresse)
VALUES
('$navn',
'$adresse')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

EDIT: And you're accessing the index of your arrays (`$_POST[navn]` and `$_POST[adresse]`) at the wrong way. You have to put the index-names in single quotes like `$_POST['navn']`.

Comment: how it solves op's problem?also other than security reasons how is your code different from op.

Comment: Well he access $_POST[navn] which is not the right way to access the index. He is missing the '' around the index-name.

Comment: you should write that to inform others what you are doing :) +1